How can I get more consistent path returns?
This does return a correct path if not using sdcards, or usb drives. But I want it to return a proper path no matter where you select.
/storage/emulated/0/folder if using internal storage.
/storage/emulated/0/A56F-U78L:folder if using usb or sdcard. The path is just an example.
If also feels incorrect.. like a hack maybe with the replace code
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.also { uri ->

                val selectedDirectory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, uri) ?: return

                // Get the primary external storage directory
                val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                val storagePath = storageDir.absolutePath

                val path = storagePath + "/" + uri.lastPathSegment?.replace("primary:", "")


I've changed it a few times, but this was the best I've gotten and I'm not happy with it.
Any ideas?
This is driving me crazy
Thanks for taking the time to look at this!
